# Dynamic data get current row data in field template

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have a dynamic data website which has a custom field template,

> CustomFieldTemplate_Edit.ascx

that will be used inside

> ListDetails.aspx

for some pages. I have set it up where I need it to using the UIHint attribute and I want to implement some custom functionality. For this I need a way to get the data of the current row that contains my CustomFieldTemplate. How can I do this ?

```
public partial class CustomFieldTemplate_Edit : System.Web.DynamicData.FieldTemplateUserControl
{
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Need to get current row data, or at least the primary key here
    }
}
```

I noticed that FieldTemplateUserControl has a `Row` property but I don't know how to use it. When I try to access it I get this error:

> "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control."

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1626234.aspx?How%20to%20access%20the%20data%20item%20current%20row%20in%20the%20field%20template%20control%20). The answer is the `Row` property of the `FieldTemplateUserControl`, but you have to access it in the `OnDataBinding` event of the FieldTemplate.

After you get the Row, you can get the entities from it using these extension methods(taken from the link above) and it all works like a charm.

```
public static class EntityDataSourceExtensions
{
    public static TEntity GetEntityAs<TEntity>(this object dataItem)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var entity = dataItem as TEntity;


        if (entity != null)
            return entity;


        var td = dataItem as ICustomTypeDescriptor;


        if (td != null)
            return (TEntity)td.GetPropertyOwner(null);


        return null;
    }


    public static Object GetEntity(this object dataItem)
    {
        var td = dataItem as ICustomTypeDescriptor;


        if (td != null)
            return td.GetPropertyOwner(null);


        return null;
    }
}
```